# How to switch between Openssl-engine and Openssl-software implementation dynamically?

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography, ecdsa

I am trying to test my openssl engine code with the software implementation in following way.

step 1: Load my openssl engine.
step 2: Sign using ECDSA with openssl-Engine (api used ECDSA_sign).
step 3: Unload openssl engine.
step 4: Verify using software implementation of openssl (api used ECDSA_verify).

I see once the engine is loaded, I can't unload the openssl engine.
I have used ENIGINE_finish and ENGINE_free api which removes structural and functional reference. Still engine refrences are not removed.

How can I switch between Openssl engine and openssl-software implementation dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you are doing something like this in step 1, where I omitted all return code checking for the sake of brevity:

```
ENGINE *e = ENGINE_by_id("dynamic");
ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(e, "SO_PATH", "my-engine", 0);
ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(e, "LOAD", NULL, 0);
ENGINE_set_default_EC(e)
```

Then, after doing your ECDSA signature calculation, I believe (without actually having tested it) that it should be sufficient to invoke, using that same value of `e`,

```
ENGINE_unregister_EC(e);
```

to switch back to the default EC implementations that come with OpenSSL and continue with your signature verification.

Note that you may have to do similar things for the digest that you are using during your signature calculation, if your engine implements that as well and if you want to test that as well.

Comment: Thank you..I have tried your suggestion today.. but ENGINE_unregister_EC(e) is stil not releasing references.. the crypto calls are still redirected to Engine implementation☹️

Comment: Hmm, that does not sound right. What does `ENGINE_get_default_EC()` return after you did that unregister? It should return something different than the pointer to your own engine. (I am assuming you are on the 1.1 branch.)